# Why is my es6 code not compiling after npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have created a npm module with es6. You can see it on github [here](https://github.com/Dakuan/backbone.lazify).

There are some scripts in the [package.json](https://github.com/Dakuan/backbone.lazify/blob/master/package.json#L6) file which should ensure that the es6 modules get built. It works when running `npm publish` and `npm install` when in the context (directory) of the npm module. Running `npm install` in another project (ie including the module as a dependency) does not however build the es6 modules. There don't seem to be any errors in the `npm-debug.log` file either.

I'd really like to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by the lack of a `.npmignore` file. As there wasn't one, npm was using the `.gitignore` file instead. This filters out the `dist/` folder which I don't want in source control. [This commit](https://github.com/Dakuan/backbone.lazify/commit/1e1d930e557b752da4af0ed5b06594f1511c49eb) fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your script is missing an `install` (or `postinstall`) script.

Comment: Yeah I thought that, but this project doesn't seem to have one: https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/package.json and somehow works

Comment: @Dakuan if you install the module from a registry, it should work because both that project and yours are using `prepublish`. However, if you install your module from a directory (`npm install /some/path/to/module`), you need an additional `install` script.

Comment: I'm doing a `npm install backbone.lazify --save` and it's not working.

Comment: @Dakuan your package contains a `.gitignore` that excludes `dist/`, and lacking a `.npmignore` this means that `dist/` won't be published (see [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the code with a script on the `prepublish` hook, then you don't need it to be built again when others install it. It should ship with the built ES6 code.

In fact, you probably want to add your src directory to your `.npmignore` file, so that it doesn't ship with any JS that can't be used directly.